# How can I change (modify) video frame rate and bit rate?

Tags: avassetexportsession, avasset

I need re-encoding a video file from photo library for web site service.
I tried below code but it has occurred error like 'video composition must have composition instructions'.

(code)

```
AVAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoFileUrl options:nil];
NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:anAsset];
if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality]) {

    self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                          initWithAsset:anAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];



    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, anAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[anAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];


    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,nil];


    AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);    // bit rate
    MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(640, 480);    // frame rate

    [self.exportSession setVideoComposition:MainCompositionInst];

    NSURL *furl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.tmpVideoPath];

    self.exportSession.outputURL = furl;

    self.exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    CMTime start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.startTime, anAsset.duration.timescale);
    CMTime duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.stopTime-self.startTime, anAsset.duration.timescale);
    CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, duration);
    self.exportSession.timeRange = range;

    self.trimBtn.hidden = YES;
    self.myActivityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.myActivityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        switch ([self.exportSession status]) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[self.exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"NONE");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.myActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    self.myActivityIndicator.hidden = YES;
                    self.trimBtn.hidden = NO;
                    [self playMovie:self.tmpVideoPath];
                });

                break;
        }
    }];

}
```

}

without the changing frame rate and bit rate, it works perfectly.
Please give me any advise.
Thanks.

Comment: if I set MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction]; , I get other error 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (AVFoundationErrorDomain error -11841'

Answer (score 1):

Framerate I'm still looking for, but bitrate has been solved by this drop in replacement for `AVAssetExportSession`: https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but some things to look at. Unfortunatley the error messages dont tell you much in these cases in AVFoundation.

In general, I  would make things simple and slowly add functionality.To start, make sure all layers start at zero and then end at the final duration. Do the same for the main composition. Invalid times may give you an error like this. **For your instruction, make sure that it starts at the same time and ends at the same time too**.